# Eclipse c++ plugin

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, macos

I have been programming in Java for quite some time using the Eclipse IDE. Now I have a project that needs to be done in C++. I've installed the C++ plugin but I can't compile my code. It can't find the libraries in my system, not even iostream.h . I've searched around the web and couldn't find anything of use.
I'm using a MacOS X Yosemite. I don't think that this part should be empty ***Project/Properties/"C/C++ General"/Paths and Symbols/Includes*** but the /usr/lib/c++ folder does not exist despite the fact I have XCode and is running c++ smoothly...

Comment: Use `iostream` (no `.h`)

Comment: What does your compiler say exactly ? Are you sure you installed your compiler properly ?

Comment: You might need to install XCode's command line tools. I forget how, but it's easy to search for.

Comment: Xcode with c++ works just fine. Meaning my libraries are in place. Thing is... Eclipse can't find them... do you know where the standard c++ library is on a mac running Yosemite?